# Error: invalid_request Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Uri must consist of printable ASCII characters:

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a client ID in the Google Developer Console and specified the same URL in my program and still it is getting the error.

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Uri must consist of printable ASCII characters:

This is my URI: `localhost:81/public/login/CheckLogin`.

Comment: Your URI contains unprintable characters. I suspect tabs and/or carriage returns. Until you provide the code you try to execute, nobody could say more.

Comment: See [Which characters make a URL invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's URL-encoded. Try using the [PHP `urlencode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). Also, it doesn't like even URL-encoded spaces (just to let you know).